# Import from module using prefix without exposing non-prefixed things

Tags: racket

I'd like to be able to only import namespaced items from a module in Racket. The prefix-in function does allow me to access functions from the module using the prefix, but it doesn't hide the old name.

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.6.
> (require (prefix-in tcp: racket/tcp))
> tcp-accept
#<procedure:tcp-accept>
> tcp:tcp-accept
#<procedure:tcp-accept>
```

Is there a simple way to hide the unprefixed names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prefix-in` form only imports the prefixed names, not the unprefixed ones. However, the `racket` language includes the `racket/tcp` module by default, so it is already imported when the REPL starts up. If you use `#lang racket/base`, instead, then `tcp-accept` won’t be imported, so the prefixed import will be the only imported identifier. You can simulate this using the `-I racket/base` option in the REPL:

```
$ racket -iI racket/base
Welcome to Racket v6.7.0.4.
> (require (prefix-in tcp: racket/tcp))
> tcp-accept
; tcp-accept: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
> tcp:tcp-accept
#<procedure:tcp-accept>
```